# Python xlwt cell overwrite

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I'm trying to parse the list "words" into one column, but I'm having a problem with cell overwrite.

```
import xlwt

wb=xlwt.Workbook()
sh=wb.add_sheet('sheet1')
sh.write(0,0,'words')

words = ["amazing","awesome","great"]
cols=['A']

for num in range(1,4):
     row = sh.row(num)
     for index,col in enumerate(cols):
             value = words[index]+str(num)
             row.write(index,value)   
wb.save('example.xls')
```

Comment: Can you show the data before and teh data after so we can see what is happening?

Comment: Note that unless you have a pressing need to stick with the older .xls format, you should be writing .xlsx files instead (using XlsxWriter or OpenPyXL; of those two, XlsxWriter is the one which is more similar to xlwt, and it's also the better library in my opinion, if all you are doing is writing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sh.write()` just as you did for the header row. Use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate) to provide the row number, starting from 1 (see second argument to `enumerate()`):

```
import xlwt

wb=xlwt.Workbook()
sh=wb.add_sheet('sheet1')
sh.write(0,0,'words')

words = ["amazing", "awesome", "great"]

for row, word in enumerate(words, start=1):
    sh.write(row, 0, word)
#    sh.write(row, 0, '{}{}'.format(word, row))    # use this if you want the row number appended

wb.save('example.xls')
```